# What am I doing wrong (Pythonista name error)?

Tags: python, scene, pythonista

I'm using Pythonista for python and am trying to use Scene to program my game. I am completely new to this. I use colortaleTitle as the name of a SpriteNode, but keep getting a name error stating that colortaleTitle is undefined. I am following the intro to the Scene documentation almost exactly (I think).

So far, I have tried renaming this, but still have not gotten the expected results.

```py
from scene import *
import time
import sound

class ColorTaleMenu (Scene):
    def setup(self):
        self.background_color = 'black'
        self.colortaleTitle = SpriteNode('colortaleTitle.png')
        self.colortaleTitle.position = colortaleTitle.size / 2
        Scene.add_child(self.colortaleTitle)
```

I want it to show colortaleTitle.png in the center of the screen.

It changes the background_color to black, but never puts in the image.

Comment: Please format the code: select it and type `ctrl-k`. [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: The example in the docs uses **self**.add_child().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is on this line:

```
self.colortaleTitle.position = colortaleTitle.size / 2
```

On the right hand side of the assignment, you're trying to access `colortaleTitle`, but that's not defined. Instead, you earlier defined `self.colortaleTitle`, which is not the same thing (it's an attribute, not a local variable). Try adding a `self.` prefix to the variable name and it should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helped.